# calling nmap from pythons subprocess module using check_output function is not working

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, nmap

I want to use a python script to use nmap. I realize there is a package for python-nmap. But I want to create a simple script that interprets the output of nmap command then does some more things depending on it's output.

Attempting to use check_output("nmap") like this link does:

[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

by running this :

```
sp.check_output(
"nmap",
stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

I get the error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'nmap' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

The command works with apt-get, ls and python.
I think it is probably that nmap is an installed program and check_output is searching in the right place to find it.

nmap works in my terminal.

Any pointers?

Comment: Try `sp.check_output("nmap",shell=True,stderr=sp.STDOUT)`

Comment: I tried that and still got the same error CalledProcessError: Command 'nmap' returned non-zero exit status 255

Comment: Well, try to run with "/full/path/to/nmap"

Comment: I used whereis nmap to find the path, its path was "/usr/bin/nmap". Tried the sp check_output with it and I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: What is your OS type and version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS trusty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.
You have to pass some arguments to nmap for successfully execution, as well 'shell' should be enabled.
Following command works:

```
subprocess.check_output("nmap -V", shell=True)
```